# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS using Virtual Hosts

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, centos7, httpd, apache2

I'm getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when entering my website, using Google Chrome.

I'm not using any rewrite module.

This is my website configuration: (Literally a Virtual Host)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mcwownetwork.net
  ServerAlias www.mcwownetwork.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

While this is my VirtualHost with SSL

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mcwownetwork.net
  ServerAlias www.mcwownetwork.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
  Redirect permanent / https://mcwownetwork.net/
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mcwownetwork.net/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mcwownetwork.net/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mcwownetwork.net/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any solution?

`httpd.conf` doesn't contain anything relevant that could cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TLS virtual host entry is redirecting to itself creating an infinite loop

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mcwownetwork.net
  Redirect permanent / https://mcwownetwork.net/
```

( you probably should move that redirect directive to the plain http virtual host entry)